# express.js share routes to render page in different way

Tags: node.js, express

I have written a page called `sponsorCenter`, but I need to control it with two routes:

```
app.get('/sponsorCenter',function(req, res){});

app.get('/sponsorCenter/all',function(req, res){});
```

The header, footer and the right columns are same.  When I change the URL, only the left column will change.

So my question is can I use just one route to judge the different access and render the page? Because only the left column is different, so I think it is not necessary to render the other parts via another route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can accept the route parameter as a variable. The same variable will be accessible to the controller in the request `req` parameter.

```
app.get('sponsorCenter/:type*?', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.type);
});
```

This would match all routes like `sponsorCenter`, `sponsorCenter/all`, `sponsorCenter/admin`, `sponsorCenter/user1` etc.